# Adding Durations to dates in a manner stable across timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js, dst, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I'm currently working with software that does computations with [date-fns Durations](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/Duration) both on the server- and client-side.

This software gathers data for a time window that is specified using Durations from a URL. The intention then is to gather data and perform computations on both sides for the same time window.

Now because of [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) there are cases where these windows do not align when adding the Durations to a current date on either end.

For example when computing `add(new Date('2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z'), { days: -16 })` in UTC the computation arrives at `2023-10-28T10:59:13.371Z`, but a browser in CET will arrive at `2023-10-28T09:59:13.371Z` instead.

### Attempted solution

I've been trying to conjure up a special `addDuration` function to add durations the way UTC does it in the hope of obtaining a reproducible way to apply durations independent of Browsers. However (because time is hard) this appears quite hard to get right and I'm not sure it is even entirely possible with what we've got. (I wish [temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) was ready to aid me in this.)

So I came up with this function:

```js
const addDuration = (date, delta) => {
  const { years = 0, months = 0, weeks = 0, days = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0 } = delta

  const dateWithCalendarDelta = add(date, { months, years, days, weeks })
  const tzDelta = date.getTimezoneOffset() - dateWithCalendarDelta.getTimezoneOffset()

  return add(dateWithCalendarDelta, { hours, minutes: minutes + tzDelta, seconds })
}
```

I then went on to test it with several examples and print outputs like this:

```js
console.table(
  examples.map(({ start, delta, utc }) => {
    const add1 = add(new Date(start), delta)
    const ok1 = add1.toISOString() === utc ? '✅' : '❌'
    const add2 = addDuration(new Date(start), delta)
    const ok2 = add2.toISOString() === utc ? '✅' : '❌'

    return { start: new Date(start), delta, utc: new Date(utc), add1, ok1, add2, ok2 }
  }),
)
```

With this I went ahead and executed the code with different `TZ` environment variables:

Output of `TZ=UTC node example.js`:
[image: Screenshot of TZ=UTC node example.js]

Output of `TZ=CET node example.js`:
[image: Screenshot of TZ=CET node example.js]

Here in the `add2` column we see how `addDuration` behaves and a ✅ is displayed in the `ok2` column when it matches the UTC output. Similarly `add1` is the behaviour of the typical `date-fns/add` function.

#### Open ends

I'd like to specifically learn more about these aspects:

- Is it generally possible to apply Durations to a Date in Browsers without shipping a whole dump of different timezone data?

  - Is there a simple way to correct the broken case for `addDuration` in `TZ=CET`?
- Is there an easy/simple way to achieve the desired outcome using date-fns? Maybe I've just overlooked something?
- Is what I'm trying here a bad idea for some reason and I just struggle to understand that?

I think I want this:

A pure function to apply Durations (deltas) to a Date independent of the local timezone. Ideally it should work the same as UTC, but that feels secondary to working the same across different browsers.

I'm under the impression that this is hindered to some extent by how Date in JavaScript behaves dependent on the local TZ.

Existence of such a function would - I think - imply that a statement such as 'yesterday' or '1 year ago' could be interpreted in a way that makes sense independent of the local TZ and independent of DST.

I know that it would be possible to gloss over the facts of how many days the current year or month have exactly and 'just' compute a number of hours for this, to then accept the same delta for all - but I'd like things like `{ months: -1 }` to work in a way that makes 'sense' for humans if possible.

### Related notes

- I've also opened a discussion about this on [date-fns GitHub](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/discussions/3578).
- I've had looks at both [date-fns-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz) and [date-fns/utc](https://github.com/date-fns/utc) and could not find good ways to use them.

#### Complete example

Here's the complete `example.js` source:

```js
// const add = require('date-fns/add')

const examples = [{
    start: '2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: 0
    },
    utc: '2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-10-29T02:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -2
    },
    utc: '2023-10-29T01:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -3
    },
    utc: '2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -4
    },
    utc: '2023-10-28T23:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z',
    delta: {
      days: -15,
      hours: -4
    },
    utc: '2023-10-29T06:59:13.371Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z',
    delta: {
      days: -16
    },
    utc: '2023-10-28T10:59:13.371Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z',
    delta: {
      days: -16,
      hours: -4
    },
    utc: '2023-10-28T06:59:13.371Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -(16 * 24 + 4)
    },
    utc: '2023-10-28T06:59:13.371Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      days: -2
    },
    utc: '2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: 0
    },
    utc: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-03-26T03:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -2
    },
    utc: '2023-03-26T02:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      hours: -3
    },
    utc: '2023-03-26T01:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-03-25T04:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      days: -1,
      hours: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-03-25T05:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-11-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-10-01T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2024-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2022-10-31T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-11-28T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-09-30T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2024-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-11-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-09-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2024-10-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2022-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-04-26T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-02-28T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2024-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2022-03-28T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-04-25T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-02-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2024-03-25T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2022-03-27T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2023-04-24T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      months: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2023-02-26T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: 1,
      days: -1
    },
    utc: '2024-03-24T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
  {
    start: '2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z',
    delta: {
      years: -1,
      days: 1
    },
    utc: '2022-03-26T00:00:00.000Z',
  },
]

const addDuration = (date, delta) => {
  const {
    years = 0, months = 0, weeks = 0, days = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0
  } = delta

  const dateWithCalendarDelta = add(date, {
    months,
    years,
    days,
    weeks
  })
  const tzDelta = date.getTimezoneOffset() - dateWithCalendarDelta.getTimezoneOffset()

  return add(dateWithCalendarDelta, {
    hours,
    minutes: minutes + tzDelta,
    seconds
  })
}

const main = () => {
  console.table(
    examples.map(({
      start,
      delta,
      utc
    }) => {
      const add1 = add(new Date(start), delta)
      const ok1 = add1.toISOString() === utc ? '✅' : '❌'
      const add2 = addDuration(new Date(start), delta)
      const ok2 = add2.toISOString() === utc ? '✅' : '❌'

      return {
        start: new Date(start),
        delta,
        utc: new Date(utc),
        add1,
        ok1,
        add2,
        ok2
      }
      document.querySelector('tbody')
    }),
  )
}

setTimeout(main, 500)
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import { add } from 'https://esm.run/date-fns';
  window.add = add;
</script>
```

Comment: Please make the snippet runnable

Comment: You need https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/date-fns@2.30.0/index.min.js instead of importing it

Comment: Hm - I struggle to find out how to correctly include that in the snippet and use it.
I've also tried my luck with https://unpkg.com/date-fns@2.30.0/index.js but in both cases I get scripts complaining about require not being present (agreeable). I'd love to have the snippet runnable, too though - thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: It was not trivial, but I managed. We need a type="module"

Comment: Thanks for figuring this one out :) I think that was exactly where I struggled.

I'm not entirely convinced it's an improvement though - for the following reasons:

1. My main intent with putting the script as a snippet was to ease reproduction - and I think one can do it in the Browser neatly usually, but here changing timezones is a good idea - and it's possible through dev tools, but maybe harder than setting an ENV.
2. It is now harder to copy the script into a local file and have it working.
3. Running it I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'examples' has already been declared".

Comment: Yeah - sorry, I'm rolling back the edit because I find that the working snippet makes it harder to explore the problem itself.

Having working console output and an ability to copy and play with the code seems to be the better trade to me.

Comment: But then it does not belong in a snippet. You can use my snippet and move the data to the end of the script

Comment: Fair point - reinstated your change with an adjustment.

Comment: Gives error alas

Comment: @JakobRunge - It's unclear from your question, are you trying to add UTC days (exact 24-hours per day), or are you trying to add days with respect to the local time zone?  You can't have it both ways, you have to pick one or the other.

Comment: Ah sorry for the unclarity. I think always and only UTC is the only good solution as long as I need to compute the same dates + durations in different clients/servers.

It seems to me now, after learning more on the topic yesterday, that Date.UTC and functions like Date.getUTC* would actually enable this.

Comment: Using PST as example, the example date is `Nov 13 2023 02:59:13 GMT-0800` and subtracting 16 days give you `Oct 28 2023 02:59:13 GMT-0700` (the hour minute seconds are same). This is the expected result. Subtracting 16 days should subtract 16 days, not 15 days 23 hours.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that an `addDuration` function is wanted that computes in UTC only, and I think that is possible using `Date.UTC` and the `Date.getUTC*` functions like this:

```js
const addDuration = (date, delta) => {
  const {
    years = 0,
    months = 0,
    weeks = 0,
    days = 0,
    hours = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    seconds = 0,
  } = delta;

  const utcYears = date.getUTCFullYear();
  const utcMonths = date.getUTCMonth();
  const utcDays = date.getUTCDate();
  const utcHours = date.getUTCHours();
  const utcMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  const utcSeconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
  const utcMilliseconds = date.getUTCMilliseconds();

  return new Date(
    Date.UTC(
      utcYears + years,
      utcMonths + months,
      utcDays + weeks * 7 + days,
      utcHours + hours,
      utcMinutes + minutes,
      utcSeconds + seconds,
      utcMilliseconds
    )
  );
};
```

I think it would satisfy the needs of calculating the same date for the same deltas and start date in different clients independent of TZ.

I understand that there are cases in general when doing these computations where different results are possible. For example when asking which date it was a month before March 31st. For these cases it is only important for me that all clients behave the same and preferentially the way JS 'does it anyway'. My understanding is that exactly this happens when asking JS to create a date for such a case:

```js
new Date(Date.UTC(2023,01,31,0,0,0,0))
// 2023-03-03T00:00:00.000Z
```

I've found that the implementation would also fit all the test cases from the example:

[image: Screenshot of executing the given example with the new suggestion of addDuration in TZ=CET]

Full code then looks like this:

```js
const add = require("date-fns/add");

const examples = [
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: 0 },
    utc: "2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -1 },
    utc: "2023-10-29T02:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -2 },
    utc: "2023-10-29T01:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -3 },
    utc: "2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T03:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -4 },
    utc: "2023-10-28T23:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z",
    delta: { days: -15, hours: -4 },
    utc: "2023-10-29T06:59:13.371Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z",
    delta: { days: -16 },
    utc: "2023-10-28T10:59:13.371Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z",
    delta: { days: -16, hours: -4 },
    utc: "2023-10-28T06:59:13.371Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-11-13T10:59:13.371Z",
    delta: { hours: -(16 * 24 + 4) },
    utc: "2023-10-28T06:59:13.371Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { days: -2 },
    utc: "2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: 0 },
    utc: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -1 },
    utc: "2023-03-26T03:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -2 },
    utc: "2023-03-26T02:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { hours: -3 },
    utc: "2023-03-26T01:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-03-25T04:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T04:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { days: -1, hours: 1 },
    utc: "2023-03-25T05:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-11-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2023-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2024-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2022-10-31T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2023-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2024-10-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-11-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2023-09-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2024-10-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-10-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2022-10-29T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2023-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2024-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2022-03-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2023-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2024-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2022-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2023-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { months: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2023-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: 1, days: -1 },
    utc: "2024-03-24T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    start: "2023-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    delta: { years: -1, days: 1 },
    utc: "2022-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
];

/**
 *
 * @param {Date} date
 * @param {*} delta
 * @returns Date
 */
const addDuration = (date, delta) => {
  const {
    years = 0,
    months = 0,
    weeks = 0,
    days = 0,
    hours = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    seconds = 0,
  } = delta;

  const utcYears = date.getUTCFullYear();
  const utcMonths = date.getUTCMonth();
  const utcDays = date.getUTCDate();
  const utcHours = date.getUTCHours();
  const utcMinutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  const utcSeconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
  const utcMilliseconds = date.getUTCMilliseconds();

  return new Date(
    Date.UTC(
      utcYears + years,
      utcMonths + months,
      utcDays + weeks * 7 + days,
      utcHours + hours,
      utcMinutes + minutes,
      utcSeconds + seconds,
      utcMilliseconds
    )
  );
};

console.table(
  examples.map(({ start, delta, utc }) => {
    const add1 = add(new Date(start), delta);
    const ok1 = add1.toISOString() === utc ? "✅" : "❌";
    const add2 = addDuration(new Date(start), delta);
    const ok2 = add2.toISOString() === utc ? "✅" : "❌";

    return {
      start: new Date(start),
      delta,
      utc: new Date(utc),
      add1,
      ok1,
      add2,
      ok2,
    };
  })
);
```